# Real part of digamma function $\Re \psi \left(xi+\frac{1}{2}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

Is there any possibility to find the Real part of $ \Re \psi \left(xi+\frac{1}{2}\right) $ digamma function?

For imaginary part of the above function, we have:

$$\Im \psi \left(xi+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\frac{\pi }{2}\tanh \left(\pi x\right)$$

Comment: No ${}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: What about $\psi(ix+1/2)-i\frac\pi2\tanh(\pi x)$?

Comment: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function#Special_values) said that "Apart from Gauss's digamma theorem, no such closed formula is known for the real part in general. We have, for example, at the imaginary unit the numerical approximation"